# Nested JSON Object Retrieval in JAVA Example

Tags: java, json

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

Class Demo{
 public static void main(String args[]){

       JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject secondJson = new JSONObject();
        secondJson.put("Secret","123214234");
        secondJson.put("Code","123214");
        secondJson.put("Data","Success");


        json.put("Demo",secondJson);

        if(json.containsKey("Demo")) {
            JSONObject msg = (JSONObject)json.get("Demo");
            if(msg.containsKey("Secret")) {
                String msg =Objects.toString(msg.get("Secret")),
                System.out.println(msg.get("Secret"));
            }

        }
   }

}
```

Comment: instead of `Objects.toString(msg.get("Secret"))` simply write `(String) msg.get("Secret");` and see if that works

Comment: Please provide a short description on what exactly you are trying to accomplish. A code snippet alone leaves too much room for guessing.